# Can you have multiple Libraries?

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I am new to working with sharepoint and I was wondering if having multiple libraries is possible.

Here is an example of how my sharepoint side links are at the moment.

[image: The side links at the moment]

Here is a picture of how i want it:

[image]

I was planning to have a project section for the department in the second half.

I have looked in the mircosoft Sharepoint 2012 Unleashed. But it only shows how to create the usual stuff like documents, web parts ect.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The title of the questions as it is (*"Can you have multiple Libraries?"*) is a bit misleading. You already have them, what you want is to organize the links in a navigation pane in a manner different from the default.

Yes, you can do that. You just have to edit the master page for your site. So it's just a matter of changing a little piece of HTML. You'll need either Visual Studio or Sharepoint Designer. The latter is free. [Here is the link for the 32 bit version](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=16573), you can google for the 64 bit one. There is no way to do that just with the browser.

Answer (score 2):

If you are looking for rearranging the navigation (Sorting/adding/updating/deleting links, changing categories), you can do the same by configuring the Quick launch

here is the link which can help you..

http://office.microsoft.com/en-in/sharepoint-server-help/configure-the-quick-launch-for-site-navigation-HA102130960.aspx

Comment: This is the better solution, changing the master page should only be done under absolute necessity.